# The requested feature is not enabled in this environment

Tags: spring, authorization, okta

I am trying to Authorize the user using okta by Making a REST call to `https://{myoktadomain}/oauth2/default/v1/authorize`. This throws the error:

> The requested feature is not enabled in this environment

can somebody help me in authorizing user using okta using custom login?

Comment: Adding related code and details will be helpful

Comment: i am now able to make it work by  making slight change to the REST Url as https://{myoktadomain}/oauth2/v1/authorize and pass the required parameters like client_id, response_type, scope, nonce, redirect_uri.

Answer (score 1):

i am now able to make it work by making slight change to the REST Url as https://{myoktadomain}/oauth2/v1/authorize and pass the required parameters like client_id, response_type, scope, nonce, redirect_uri and make a GET Call.

Here is the link for more details. https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#authorize